# Number of broadcasts to allow 95% of node pairs to exchange in directed graph

Tags: graph, graph-theory, broadcast

I have a **directed unweighted graph** with N nodes and E edges. Nodes are of an average degree 2E/N.

In the first round, nodes each broadcast their information to all their neighbours. In subsequent rounds, nodes broadcast the information received from their neighbours during the previous round to all other neighbours, and so forth.

The graph is not guaranteed to be acyclic.

My question is: **how many consecutive rounds of broadcast are required, on average, for 95% of node pairs to have reached one another?** Is it possible to calculate an approximate figure based on the average degree of the graph?

Comment: Since your graph is directed, there are cases where information won't propagate. Therefore the average is infinite.

Comment: **average** is a very broad concept -- say you have a worst case `a->b->c->d` and all other topologies are "nice", what should the weight / frequency of worst case be? `0.5**3`? 50%? 1%?

Comment: @LiorKogan good observation, e.g. in a case like `a->x; b->x; c->x` node x will learn entire graph, by a,b,c will never learn their siblings. That in itself doesn't guarantee infinite 95-percentile though, does it? For example OP could constrain graph to have less than 5% leaf (and thus root) nodes. Or to *typically* have such guarantee

Comment: I'm looking for the typical case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By average, I assume you mean average over all possible (N,E) directed graphs with no multiple edges.

**Theorem 1**

If E <= (N-1)^2, there will be at least one graph where information won't propagate.

**Proof**

A directed graph with N nodes has up to N(N-1) edges. Consider a complete graph, select a node, and remove all its outgoing edges (Alternatively, we can remove all its incoming edges). Information from this node cannot propagate, and we are left with N(N-1)-(N-1) = (N-1)^2 edges.

**Corollary 1**

When E <= (N-1)^2, there is at least one graph where information cannot propagate, therefore the average number of rounds is infinite.

---

**Theorem 2a**

If E > (N-1)^2 the maximal number of rounds is 2.

**Proof**

A directed graph with N nodes and E > (N-1)^2 edges is a complete graph where up to (N-2) edges removed.

If we want to remove edges from a complete graph such the the number of rounds will be 3 (e.g. from node A to node B), we'll need to make sure there is no node B and edges A->B and B->C. This means that we need to remove at least one edge (either A->B or B->C) for each of the (N-2) possible 'B' nodes. We also need to remove the direct A->C edge. In total we need to remove (N-3) edges.

---

**Theorem 2b**

If E > (N-1)^2 the *minimal* number of rounds is 2.

**Proof**

Trivial. The graph is incomplete, therefore there is at least one path of length 2.

**Corollary 2**

if (N-1)^2 < E < N(N-1), the number of rounds is 2.

---

**Theorem 3**

If E = N(N-1), the number of rounds is 1

**Proof**

Trivial. Complete graph.

---

Now, you are asking about more than 95% of the node pairs.

Of course we can build some (N-1)^2 < E < N(N-1) graphs, where >= 95% of ordered-node-pairs can communicate in 1 round, but the other ordered-node-pairs communicate in 2 rounds.

This is trivial if you consider a complete directed graph of 6 nodes where only one edge is removed. (6*5-1) / (6*5) = 96.66% of the ordered-node-pairs can communicate in one round.

Why do you ask specifically about 95%? Is it important to derive calculations for exactly this number? Let us know. I don't think that you can derive a simple accurate generic formula, especially when N and E are small. Maybe we can formulate something asymptotically (for very large N).

Comment: I'm modelling a graph algorithm using message passing. Accuracy of the solution will depend on how complete the message exchange process is. The number 95% is not important, I'd just like to be able to calculate a typical case bound on the number of nodes that might be left out from the calculation.

Comment: If so, i believe i  answered your question ;-)